# Ionic 4 Angular - How to self dismiss a modal

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

In Ionic 3, dismissing a modal was pretty simple:

```
constructor(viewCtrl: ViewController) {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss()
}
```

In Ionic 4, I can't import `ViewController` (or to be accurate, my IDE tries to import a type of ViewController).

I was wondering what the new approach of dismissing a modal is.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to the docs, it looks like the `dismiss` method has moved to [ModalController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/modal/ModalController/).

So to dismiss a modal, I need to do:

```
constructor(modalCtrl: ModalController) {
  modalCtrl.dismiss();
}
```

How i(r)onic that I find my answer AFTER I post the question.

Comment: @MohamedSaleh https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal-controller

Comment: @Elliya I have managed to do it, but with calling the dismiss from an onclick function not like you advised

Comment: How ionic* FTFY

Comment: @Michael Artman fixed

Answer (score 11):

the ionic v4 documentation seems to be missing here yet I believe the correct way to access `dismiss` from the modal is:

```
import { Components } from '@ionic/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-modal',
  templateUrl: 'some-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['some-modal.component.scss']
})
export class SomeModalComponent {
  // modal is available here where created with:
  // modalController.create({ component: SomeModalComponent})
  @Input() modal: Components.IonModal;

  onCancel = () =>
    this.modal.dismiss('cancel');
}
```

while the `modal` is actually of type `HTMLIonModalElement` I am using `Components.IonModal` since `HTMLIonModalElement` is supposed to be global yet it is not visible to WebStorm/IntelliJ for some reason.

Comment: Thank you @ciekawy - one day when Google prioritizes v4 over v3 documentation and when there is enough Stack Overflow answers to fill the gaps of missing documentation using Ionic will be so much fun! :D

Comment: Writing from the future, it's still a nightmare because the framework is completely reinvented every 9 months.

Answer (score 5):

To dismiss a modal in ionic v4. Do the following in your ionic modal component

```
    export class ExampleModalComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private modalCtrl: ModalController) {

      }

      async closeModal() {
        await this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
      }
    }
```

In Your Components HTML the button should look something like this.

```
<ion-button (click)="closeModal()">
  <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the self dismiss the modal like this.

```
constructor(
    private modal: ModalController,
) { }

dismiss() {
    this.modal.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on ionic 6

the modal can dismiss put `(click)="modal.dismiss()"`:

```
<ion-modal #modal [keepContentsMounted]="true" (click)="modal.dismiss()">
```